# Comparing ViewController to a type in swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uiviewcontroller, comparison

```
extension UIViewController {
    func getChildViewController<T>(OfType: T) {
        let classType = Mirror(reflecting: self.childViewControllers.first).subjectType

        if classType == T.self {
            print("there is a match")
        }
    }
}
```

This is an extension to UIViewController, and when you call this function, you pass it a type for example:

```
ViewController.getChildViewController(OfType: SecondViewController.self)
```

This will check if the first child of view controller if of type SecondViewController

But in the if statement I am getting the error:

```
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any.Type' and 'T'
```

Comment: I somehow successfully compiled this in Swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to cast it as: any.Type

```
let passedType = ofType as? Any.Type
if classType == passedType {
    print("there is a match")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `isKindOf` in Swift 3 is just `is` so you should use something like:

```
if classType is SecondViewController {
   print("there is a match")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just calling the generic, when you need to call the parameter name for the generic.

Have you tried:

```
if classType == ofType.self { ...
```

Comment: ah, yes just tried that still get the error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any.Type' and 'T'

Answer (score 0):

I think should use ===
Apple swift programming language p.768